# Trying to create a program in Python that changes names from said .txt file into usernames

Tags: python, computer-science

So basically I am making a program that writes the .txt file and changes the names in form by last to first like Woods, Tiger and turn them into usernames in this form twoods. They have to be formatted all in lower case and I think I messed up my code somewhere. Thanks!

**The code I tried, below:**

```py
def main():
    
    user_input = input("Please enter the file name: ")
    user_file = open(user_input, 'r')
    line = user_file.readlines()
    line.split()
    while line != '':
        line = user_file.readline()
        print(line.split()[-1][0][0:6]+line.split()[0][0:6]).lower() , end = '')
    user_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: can You explain a bit better the issue? I am confused about form and writing text file. what kind of form? to my understanding is that people input their names and then only the last name is written on the txt file

Comment: Welcome! Try splitting your line on the comma plus whitespace, i.e. `line.split(', ')`. I'd also recommend you make these each a variable, e.g. `first_name, last_name = line.split... , line.split...`. Then printing your username can be really easy: `f"{first_name[0]}{last_name}"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
line = "Tiger Woods"
(fname, lname) = line.split(" ")
print(f'{fname[0:1]}{lname}'.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a couple of little issues preventing this from working / things that can be improved,

1. You are trying to `split` a list which is not possible. This is a string operation.
2. You are manually closing the file, this is not ideal
3. The program will not run as you are not using `__name__ == "__main__"`

Amended code,

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Please enter the file name: ")
    with open(user_input, 'r') as file_handler:
        for line in file_handler:
            print((line.split()[-1][0][0:6] + line.split()[0][0:6]).lower(), end='')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to read `Surname,Name` from a file line by line and turn them into `nsurname` formatted usernames.

For that, we can `open and read the file` to get user informations and `split them line by line` and `strip the \n` at the end.

After that, we can loop the lines that we read and create the usernames with given format and append them to an array of usernames.

Code:

```
# Get filename to read.
user_input = input("Please enter the file name: ")

# Open the given file and readlines.
# Split to lines and strip the \n at the end.
user_names = []
with open(user_input,'r') as user_file:
    user_names = user_file.readlines()
    user_names = [line.rstrip() for line in user_names]

print("User names from file: " + str(user_names))

# Loop the user informations that we read and split from file.
# Create formatted usernames and append to usernames list.
usernames = []
for line in user_names:
    info = line.split(',')
    username = (info[1][0:1] + info[0]).lower()
    usernames.append(username)

print("Usernames after formatted: " + str(usernames))
```

Input File(test.txt):

```
Woods,Tiger
World,Hello
```

Output:

```
Please enter the file name: test.txt
User names from file: ['Woods,Tiger', 'World,Hello']
Usernames after formatted: ['twoods', 'hworld']
```